# Does not call delegate method in FlurryAdBanner

Tags: ios, objective-c, flurry

i need to display FlurryAdBanner banner in bottom of the page.here is my code

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    FlurrySessionBuilder* builder = [[[[[FlurrySessionBuilder new]
                                        withLogLevel:FlurryLogLevelAll]
                                       withCrashReporting:YES]
                                      withSessionContinueSeconds:10]
                                     withAppVersion:@"0.1.2"];

    [Flurry startSession:@"PGQ4YPRDNXWR7MRK745M" withSessionBuilder:builder];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return YES;
}
```

ViewController. code

```
@interface ViewController ()<FlurryAdBannerDelegate>
{
    FlurryAdBanner* adBanner;
}
@end

@implementation ViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    adBanner = [[FlurryAdBanner alloc] initWithSpace:@"bottomAdd"];
    adBanner.adDelegate = self;
    [adBanner fetchAndDisplayAdInView:self.view viewControllerForPresentation:self];

}
- (void) adBannerDidFetchAd:(FlurryAdBanner*)bannerAd{
    NSLog(@" Ad Space [%@] Did Receive Ad ===== ", bannerAd );
    [bannerAd displayAdInView:self.view viewControllerForPresentation:self];
}

- (void) adBannerDidRender:(FlurryAdBanner*)bannerAd {
    NSLog(@" Ad Space [%@] Did Display Ad ===== ", [bannerAd space]);


}

- (void) adBannerWillPresentFullscreen:(FlurryAdBanner*)bannerAd{
    NSLog(@" Ad Space [%@] Will Present Fullscreen Ad ===== ", [bannerAd space]);
}

- (void) adBanner:(FlurryAdBanner*) bannerAd adError:(FlurryAdError) adError errorDescription:(NSError*) errorDescription{
    NSLog(@" Ad Space [%@] Did Fail to Receive Ad with error [%@] ===== ", [bannerAd space], errorDescription);
}

- (void) adBannerDidReceiveClick:(FlurryAdBanner*)bannerAd{
    NSLog(@" Ad Space [%@] Did Receive Click  ===== ", [bannerAd space]);
}

- (void) adBannerDidDismissFullscreen:(FlurryAdBanner*)bannerAd {

    NSLog(@" Ad Space [%@] Will Dismiss for  ===== ", [bannerAd space]);
}


- (void) adBannerWillLeaveApplication:(FlurryAdBanner*)bannerAd {
    NSLog(@" Ad Space [%@] Will Leave Application ===== ", [bannerAd space]);
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

in yahoo developer i create the app unitID.does not know what was the problem.does not called any delegate.pls help me.

Answer (score 0):

Switch your viewDidAppear and adBannerDidFetchAd to the code below. You have fetch and display in the view, but a second display in the adBannerDidFetchAd as well

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    adBanner = [[FlurryAdBanner alloc] initWithSpace:@"bottomAdd"];
    adBanner.adDelegate = self;
    viewControllerForPresentation:self];
    [adBanner fetchAdForFrame:self.view.frame];

}
- (void) adBannerDidFetchAd:(FlurryAdBanner*)bannerAd{
    NSLog(@" Ad Space [%@] Did Receive Ad ===== ", bannerAd );
    [bannerAd displayAdInView:self.view viewControllerForPresentation:self];
}
```